# Value error in Pandas on read_csv on "::" separator

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am experiencing a "ValueError" upon running the code below on the file "ratings.dat". I have tried the same code on another file with "," as a separator without any problems. However, pandas seem to be failing when the separators are "::".

Am I typing the code wrong?

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

r_cols = ['userId', 'movieId', 'rating']
r_types = {'userId': np.str, 'movieId': np.str, 'rating': np.float64}
ratings = pd.read_csv(
        r'C:\\Users\\Admin\\OneDrive\\Documents\\_Learn!\\'
        r'Learn Data Science\\Data Sets\\MovieLens\\ml-1m\\ratings.dat', 
        sep='::', names=r_cols, usecols=range(3), dtype=r_types
        )

m_cols = ['movieId', 'title']
m_types = {'movieId': np.str, 'title': np.str}
movies = pd.read_csv(
        r'C:\\Users\\Admin\\OneDrive\\Documents\\_Learn!\\'
        r'Learn Data Science\\Data Sets\\MovieLens\\ml-1m\\movies.dat', 
        sep='::', names=m_cols, usecols=range(2), dtype=m_types
        )

ratings = pd.merge(movies, ratings)
ratings.head()
```

**"ratings.dat"**

```
1::1287::5::978302039
1::2804::5::978300719
1::594::4::978302268
1::919::4::978301368
1::595::5::978824268
```

**Error Output:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-19-a2649e528fb9> in <module>()
      7         r'C:\\Users\\Admin\\OneDrive\\Documents\\_Learn!\\'
      8         r'Learn Data Science\\Data Sets\\MovieLens\\ml-1m\\ratings.dat',
----> 9         sep='::', names=r_cols, usecols=range(3), dtype=r_types
     10         )
     11 
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, dialect, compression, doublequote, escapechar, quotechar, quoting, skipinitialspace, lineterminator, header, index_col, names, prefix, skiprows, skipfooter, skip_footer, na_values, true_values, false_values, delimiter, converters, dtype, usecols, engine, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, na_filter, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, warn_bad_lines, error_bad_lines, keep_default_na, thousands, comment, decimal, parse_dates, keep_date_col, dayfirst, date_parser, memory_map, float_precision, nrows, iterator, chunksize, verbose, encoding, squeeze, mangle_dupe_cols, tupleize_cols, infer_datetime_format, skip_blank_lines)
    496                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    497 
--> 498         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    499 
    500     parser_f.__name__ = name
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    273 
    274     # Create the parser.
--> 275     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    276 
    277     if (nrows is not None) and (chunksize is not None):
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    584 
    585         # might mutate self.engine
--> 586         self.options, self.engine = self._clean_options(options, engine)
    587         if 'has_index_names' in kwds:
    588             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _clean_options(self, options, engine)
    663                         msg += " (Note the 'converters' option provides"\
    664                                " similar functionality.)"
--> 665                     raise ValueError(msg)
    666                 del result[arg]
    667 
ValueError: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators, but this causes 'dtype' to be ignored as it is not supported by the 'python' engine. (Note the 'converters' option provides similar functionality.)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the last line of the traceback carefully, you may get the answer to why it is failing. I've spit it up into two lines

> ValueError: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators,
>
> but this causes 'dtype' to be ignored as it is not supported by the 'python' engine. (Note the 'converters' option provides similar functionality.)

So the separator `'::'` is interpreted as a regular expression. As the Pandas documentation about `sep` says:

> Regular expressions are accepted and will **force** use of the python parsing engine

(emphasis mine)

Thus, Pandas will use the "Python engine" to read the data. The next line of the error then says that because of this use of the Python engine, `dtype` is ignored. (Presumably, C-engine means numpy, which can use dtype; Python obviously doesn't deal with dtypes.)

---

## How to solve it

You can either to remove the `dtype` argument from your call to `read_csv` (you'll still get a warning), or do something about the separator.

The second option appears to be tricky: escaping or a raw string don't help. Apparently, any separator more than 1 character long is interpreted by Pandas a regular expression. That may be an unfortunate decision on the Pandas side of things.

One way to avoid all this is to use a single `':'` as a separator, and avoid every other (empty) column. For example:

```
ratings = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=':', names=r_cols,
                      usecols=[0, 2, 4], dtype=r_types)
```

(or use `usecols=range(0, 5, 2)` if you're set on using `range`.)

---

## Addendum

The OP correctly raises the point about a field having a single `:` character. Perhaps there is a way around this, but otherwise you can make it a two-step approach, using numpy's `genfromtxt` instead:

```
# genfromtxt requires a proper numpy dtype, not a dict
# for Python 3, we need U10 for strings
dtype = np.dtype([('userId', 'U10'), ('movieID', 'U10'),
                  ('rating', np.float64)])
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype=dtype, names=r_cols,
                     delimiter='::', usecols=list(range(3)))
ratings = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: One of the data records has a single ":" within the data field. Hence, Python keeps throwing up a C error: "Expected 5 fields in line 12, saw 6". Is there anyway to deal with this?

Comment: At that point, I would probably open up the data file in a text editor, see if there are e.g. any commas or semi-colons in the file, and do a replace-all for '::' with ','. Provided of course that I have access to the file.

Comment: @Cloud You may want to ask about your situation at the Pandas mailing list (how to avoid `'::'` being interpretered as a regular expression; backslashes didn't work when I tested this. Or file an issue at Pandas github page.

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me is changing the engine to `'python'`:

`df = pd.read_csv(file,sep="::",engine ='python', skip_blank_lines=True)`

PS. I am using different python versions for python3 and python.